# ARM function declaring macro

Tags: macros

Thanks for reading first.

I'm trying to understand some code from OPTEE-OS.

This a part of macro and seems trying to declaring a function.

```
.macro LOCAL_FUNC name colon                
    .section .text.\name                    
    .func \name                             
    .type \name , %function                 
    \name \colon                            
    .endm
```

This function would be located in ***.text*** section.

And my question is What is the purpose of below code?

```
\name \colon
```

And also in below code,

```
.macro END_FUNC name 
    .size \name , .-\name
    .endfunc
    .endm
```

Why the ***.size*** should be written there?

Thanks for answering previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\name \colon` will create a label with the given name, because labels in ARM assembly language are given by a string followed by a colon.  This will allow code following an expansion of the LOCAL_FUNC macro to be called by branching to a label of the same name.

The `\size` directive calculates the amount of space that is being used by the thing that a symbol points to, which means that the linker can then exclude that symbol entirely if it is unused.  See [this blog post](https://community.arm.com/processors/b/blog/posts/useful-assembler-directives-and-macros-for-the-gnu-assembler) for more on `\size`.